# Trace Dynamics - Stephen L. Adler

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I recently came across "Trace Dynamics" which claims that Quantum Theory is an Emergent Phenomenon.
Stephen L. Adler is behind the idea

I was wondering whether there's a debate about his claim in the Academia

You may read about his here and here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_L._Adler
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504214